# Proxy output does not change even if there is proxies argument in request html

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I am creating a program to identify if the argument proxies in request html is working but I think it is not, when I search in google "what is my IP" and scrape it, it returns my original IP address and not the IP that I am passing to the proxies argument in get request, please see code below:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

#do google search 'what is my IP'
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+IP&oq=what+is+my+IP&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.13217j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
session = HTMLSession()
r=session.get(url,proxies={'http': 'http://161.202.226.194:80'})
r.html.render(timeout=25)
ip = r.html.xpath("//span[@style='font-size:20px']").text
print(ip)
```

The output of of ip is my IP address but I am expecting '161.202.226.194:80' which is passed on the proxies argument. please help. thanks